# Which polynomials are "transitive" with respect to $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Given a polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and a ring $R$, call $P$ transitive with respect to $R$ if and only if for all $r \in R$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $P^n(0)=r,$ where $P^n$ refers to the $n$-fold composite $$P^n = \underbrace{P \circ \cdots \circ P}_n.$$

Observe, for example, that the degree-$1$ polynomial $P(x) = x+a$ is transitive with respect to $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a$ and $r$ are coprime. I'm looking for a generalization of this statement.

> **Question.** Is there a useful characterization of which polynomials $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ are transitive with respect to $\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ generalizing the above comment, that's at least somewhat easier than simply repeatedly applying $P$?

Comment: So since any divisor of the constant term of $P$ will also divide such a composite, it is necessary that this constant term is coprime to $r$, just like the degree $1$ case. It seems a lot harder to find sufficient conditions.

Comment: Do you know any other example? A quadratic one, for instance?